# load styles in vue component package (npm)

Tags: vue.js, npm

I made vue component package and published it into npm.
It's work but the styles of the component are not loaded!

i made package with that command:

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name test-package ./src/index.js
```

and its part of my package.json:

```
"style": "./dist/test-package.css",
"main": "./dist/test-package.common.js",
```

and its styles of component:

```
<style scoped>
  .my-bg {
     backgorund: red;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a way to reproduce, it's impossible to know what exactly in your configuration causes this behavior. (By default CSS should be included, so you have some setting somewhere interfering).

[This discussion](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1287) contains a few possible fixes:

- if your `package.json` contains: `sideeffects: false`, either remove it or change it to: `sideEffects: ['*.css']`
- add `css: { extract: false }` to your `vue.config.js`'s `module.exports`

Possibly related [webpack/issues/6741](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6741):

---

*Note*: if you don't already have a [vue.config.js](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js), create it in root, with these contents:

```
module.exports = {
  css: { extract: false }
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but im not using webpack.config file

Comment: @Ahmad, you might not be using it, but Vue is, unless you changed it to use a different module bundler. `vue.config.js` is a file you can place in your project's root and interact with `webpack.config.js`, which is in `@vue/cli-service/webpack.config.js`. Are you using a different bundler? If so, which one?

Comment: Thanks, I created the vue.config.js file and put css: { extract: false } in it, it worked perfectly!